# How to fix "Error in varImp(object = model_gbm): trying to get slot "responses" from an object (class "train") that is not an S4 object

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to compute the importance of variables using models in Caret, but I keep getting the error. I have tried multiple models and with different selections of features.

The outcome is a numeric variable and the predictors are also numeric.

```
model_gbm<-train(trainSet[,predictors],trainSet[,outcomeName],method='gbm')
varImp(object=model_gbm)
```

This is the error I got:

> "Error in varImp(object = model_gbm): trying to get slot "responses" from an object (class "train") that is not an S4 object"

Comment: Could you provide a sample of `trainnSet` with `dput`? Do so for predictors and outcome name too.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you installed too many packages.

Just try this:

```
caret::varImp(model_gbm)
```

Comment: You need to include the library gbm as well